# pointers in C++ (need overview)

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
int * p1, * p2;

p1 = &firstvalue;  
p2 = &secondvalue; 
*p1 = 10;    //line 1      
*p2 = *p1;  //line 2       
 p1 = p2;   //line 3        
*p1 = 20;          

cout << "firstvalue is " << firstvalue << '\n';
cout << "secondvalue is " << secondvalue << '\n';
return 0;
```

My Analysis of this code:
p1 points to the first value and p2 points to the second value. Now, p1 points to value 10. My first question is :

Does this means that first value now stores 10. (line 1)

According to me, line 2 means that p2 and p1 point to the value stored at the address of the second value. AM I correct or wrong?

Lastly, I have no clue of line 3. So, need some help over there too.

Comment: *"Now, p1 points to value 10"* - No, it still points to `firstvalue`. A bare value is not something you can point at.

Comment: And if you haven't a clue, I suggest you just add printing statements in between all the assignments. That way you'll see more than just the final result.

Comment: (1) Yes.  (2) Wrong. (3) It does what you think line 2 does.

Comment: So, at line 1, we have updated the value of first value using pointer p1.

Comment: Take a piece of paper. Draw 2 empty boxes, one for each variable (variable = named memory location). On the bottom side of each box put their names: "first" and "second". Write some random addresses on top of these boxes , e.g. 0x0020 and 0x0024. Draw two more boxes: write "p1" and "p2" at the bottom, write random addresses at the top. Initially your boxes are empty (in reality they contain garbage). Now go through your program one statement at a time and execute it (still on paper).

Comment: First, write "5" inside the box "first". Then "15" inside "second".  Then write 0x0020 inside the box "p1" and 0x0024 inside "p2". Draw arrows from p1 to first and from p2 to second. Go on.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1: p1 still points to firstValue, but the value of firstValue is now changed to 10
Answer 2: in line 2, secondValue is assigned the value of firstValue.
Answer 3: line 3 is assigning the pointer of secondValue to the p1, so any changes in *p1 will reflect in the changed value of secondValue.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

- **Does this means that first value now stores 10. (line 1)**

Yes.

- **line 2 means that p2 and p1 point to the value stored at the address of the second value.**

No. It means that the value `p2` points to gets a copy of the value that `p1` points to. It is the equivalent of saying `secondvalue = firstvalue;` because `p2` points to `secondvalue` and `p1` points to `firatvalue` and the `*` in `*p1` or `*p2` in this context accesses the value the pointer points to.

- **I have no clue of line 3.**

This says that `p1` will now point at the same place that `p2` points to. So both `p1` and `p2` point to `secondvalue`.

Answer (score 0):

Forget syntax for a second and think about what those objects are. 
A memory location has exactly two properties, location and content.

int firstvalue; reserves a memory location (its size does not matter here).
firstvalue = 5; stores a value there.

firstvalue is a label associated with the memory address, &firstvalue is that address.
A pointer is a variable containing an address, dereferencing with '*' gives you the content at that address.

So now

```
p1 = &firstvalue;  //address of firstvalue stored in pointer p1
p2 = &secondvalue; // same thing for p2 and secondvalue 
*p1 = 10; //line 1: value 10 to variable pointed to by p1 i.e. firstvalue
*p2 = *p1;    //line  2: copy firstvalue to secondvalue 
 p1 = p2;     //line 3:  now both point to secondvalue
```

Ok?

Answer (score 0):

Lets understand what is a pointer - Pointer is storage of address it does not store value itself in light of it lets analyze the code line by line

1) Line 1 - Defined two variables (space to hold value)

2) Line 2 - Defined two pointers (space to hold address)

3) Line 4 & 5 - assigned address of the variables to pointers p1 & p2 now p1 points to location where value 5 is stored and p2 points to a location where 15 is stored

4) Line 6 - Value 10 is stored at the location p1 is pointing this means value of the variable firstvalue is changed from 5 to 10

5) Line 7 - Value of the location pointed by p1 is copied to location pointed by p2. Now both firstvalue and secondvalue is same which is 10

6) Line 8 - Value of the p2 pointer (which is address of secondvalue variable) is assigned to p1. now p1 and p2 both points to secondvalue variable

7) Line 9 - Assigned value 20 to the location pointed by pointer p1 which is now secondvalue variable

Result - both output will show value 20 as both pointers are now pointing to secondvalue variable and it is update to 20 at Line number 9

Answer (score 0):

There you go...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
    int * p1, *p2;

    p1 = &firstvalue;
    p2 = &secondvalue;
    cout << "firstvalue address: ," << &firstvalue << "p1 address: ," << p1 << "p1 Value " << *p1 << endl;
    *p1 = 10;    //line 1      
    *p2 = *p1;  //line 2 
    cout <<  "p1 Value " << *p1 << "p2 Value " << *p2 << endl;
    p1 = p2;   //line 3        
    cout << "p1 address: ," << p1 << "p2 address: ," << p2 << endl;
    *p1 = 20;
    cout << "p1 value: " << *p1 << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

output:

firstvalue address: 0115FA74,p1 address: 0115FA74,p1 Value 5

p1 Value 10, p2 Value 10

p1 address: 0115FA68,p2 address: 0115FA68

p1 value: 20

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your analysis is incorrect.

Starting with the first part of your code

> ```
> int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
> int * p1, * p2;
>
> p1 = &firstvalue;  
> p2 = &secondvalue;
> ```

and your analysis of it

> p1 points to the first value and p2 points to the second value.

Your analysis is roughly correct.   I'll give a slightly more complete description.

`p1` is a variable of type `int *` (i.r. a pointer to an `int`).   The assignment `p1 = &firstvalue` assigns the value of `p1` to be the address of the variable `firstvalue`.    This is sometimes said to mean that the pointer `p1` is assigned to point at `firstvalue`.

The same description applies to `p2` and `secondvalue`.

Now, for the next statement

> ```
> *p1 = 10;    //line 1
> ```

and your analysis of it

> Now, p1 points to value 10.

This is incorrect.   `p1` does not point to the value `10`.

The statement, `*p1 = 10` assigns the value `10` to the result of `*p1`.   `*p1` is a reference to whatever `p1` points at, which (as per above) is `firstvalue`.   Accordingly, the assignment `*p1 = 10` has the effect of assigning `firstvalue` to the value `10`.

This brings us to your first question (albeit one you wrote without a question mark).

> Does this means that first value now stores 10. (line 1)

If by "first value" you mean "the variable named `firstvalue`", the answer here is "yes".

Now, we come to the next code statement

> ```
> *p2 = *p1;  //line 2
> ```

and your analysis

> According to me, line 2 means that p2 and p1 point to the value stored at the address of the second value. AM I correct or wrong?

You are completely and utterly wrong here.

To better understand, let's break the statement into parts.  `*p1` obtains a reference to the variable pointed to by `p1` - which is `firstvalue` (which has a value `10`).   `*p2` obtains a reference to the variable pointed to by `p2` - which is `secondvalue`.    The assignment `*p2 = *p1` therefore has the same effect as `secondvalue = firstvalue`.

`p1` still points at (contains the address of) `firstvalue`.   Similarly, `p2` still points at `secondvalue`.   Both variables `firstvalue` and `secondvalue` have the value `10`.

Now we come to line 3

> ```
> p1 = p2;   //line 3
> ```

And your observation about it it

> Lastly, I have no clue of line 3. So, need some help over there too.

Uh hu.

`p2` is a pointer, and its value is `&secondvalue` - the address of `secondvalue`.   The assignment `p1 = p2` assign the value of `p1` to equal the value of `p2`.   This means that `p1` and `p2` both contain the value `&secondvalue`.   (Or that both the pointers `p1` and `p2` point to `secondvalue`).

A consequence is that

> ```
> *p1 = 20;
> ```

has the effect of assigning `secondvalue` to have the value `20`.   `firstvalue` is unaffected, and still contains the value `10`.